# XNA keyboad state to character

Tags: c#, input, xna, keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Correctly getting key being pressed for chat in XNA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9558690/correctly-getting-key-being-pressed-for-chat-in-xna)

I'm working in c# on an XNA project and I'm in the process of building a couple of simple classes to produce form elements such as text fields for user input.

The problem is that I can't seem to find any classes that translate keyboard states to characters taking into account the language selected by the user in Windows.

I did some research and apparently there is a function called toUnicode that does exactly that (or so I think) but it's only available in c++ in Winuser.h. XNA on the other hand is strictly c#, so I can't use that.

Any ideas where I could find an identical solution in c#?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

May want to check here just as a primer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff966426.aspx
(using a resx file with keyboard mappings is probably what you want.

But just to be clear, can't you just use the ordinal key value (KeyValue) ? Most control keys and arrows and such are universal. If you're doing WASD for movement then for sure you'd have to build a resource file for each culture and load them independently.